# Choosing the function in a selfmade function with tidyeval

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

So this example is basically from https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html#patterns-for-single-arguments and it works just fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)
group_mean <- function(df, group_var, summary_var){
  group_var <-  rlang::enquo(group_var)
  summary_var <-rlang::enquo(summary_var)

  name <- paste0(rlang::quo_name(summary_var), "_mean")

  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!group_var) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(!!name := mean(!!summary_var, na.rm = TRUE))
}

mtcars %>% group_mean(group_var = cyl, summary_var = disp)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl disp_mean
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     4      105.
#> 2     6      183.
#> 3     8      353.
```

I would like to e.g. be able to choose median instead of mean sometimes and e.g. change the function name to `group_stat()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this. I'm not quite sure exactly how this works but I've seen this method used in the source code of `library(purrr)` for `as_mapper()`:

https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/R/as_mapper.R

```r
library(tidyverse)

group_stat <- function(df, group_var, summary_var, .f) {

    func <- rlang::as_closure(.f)

    group_var <-  rlang::enquo(group_var)
    summary_var <-rlang::enquo(summary_var)

    name <- paste0(rlang::quo_name(summary_var), "_", deparse(substitute(.f)))

    df %>%
        dplyr::group_by(!!group_var) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(!!name := func(!!summary_var, na.rm = TRUE))
}

mtcars %>% 
    group_stat(group_var = cyl, summary_var = disp, median)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl disp_median
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     4        108 
#> 2     6        168.
#> 3     8        350.

mtcars %>% 
    group_stat(group_var = cyl, summary_var = disp, mean)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl disp_mean
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     4      105.
#> 2     6      183.
#> 3     8      353.

mtcars %>% 
    group_stat(group_var = cyl, summary_var = disp, max)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl disp_max
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     4     147.
#> 2     6     258 
#> 3     8     472

mtcars %>% 
    group_stat(group_var = cyl, summary_var = disp, min)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl disp_min
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     4     71.1
#> 2     6    145  
#> 3     8    276.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the `rlang::as_closure()` step, although there may be something better about it.  See [here](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-use-functions-as-arguments-in-r/) to see an example of using the function argument directly in place of the function.  Also, I only recently learned that the "rlang" approach to `deparse(substitute(...))` is `rlang::as_name(enquo(...))`. :)

Comment: @aosmith For some reason `as_name(enquo(.f))` doesn't work in my code. Unsure why that is. Also re using `as_closure()`, i think there is also `rlang::as_function()`. Like you I'm unsure why that might be better than just using the function argument directly.

Comment: @aosmith & @dylanjm: but ``rlang::as_name(enquo(.f))`` does not but and I get this message: ``Error: Can't convert a function to a string``.

Comment: @David Yes, it looks like it only works with `enquo()` without the `as_closure()` line, using `.f` as both the string for the names and directly as the function.   I have no idea why this would be. :D

Comment: @aosmith: Thanks, I have posted a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957264/using-the-pipe-in-selfmade-function-with-tidyeval-quo-name). It is more about combining functions with the pipe...

Comment: @David Or you can make a variable to pass to `as_name()` prior to creating `func`, like `.f2 = enquo(.f)`. I believe one reason to use `as_closure()` or `as_function()` is if you want the option to pass function names as strings and bare names.

Comment: @aosmith: does the above all work with n() as a function.

Comment: @David I don't see how `n()` could work in this context at all, since it doesn't take any arguments.  Maybe you'd want `length()` instead?  But, yes, it is possible to use `.f = n` with `as_name()` if you set `summarize()` up without arguments in the function.

Comment: @David Echoing what aosmith said. You'd have to restructure your function so that your `func` in summarize doesn't take any parameters by default. I will also mention that this function will also take partial functions. For instance you can set `.f = partial(quantile, probs=.75)` to get the 75th percentile of each group. It will kind of mess up your column titles though. But you can potentially use `partial()` for all other functions, for example `partial(mean, na.rm=T)`

Comment: @dylanjm & @aosmith: it works with ``quantile``, but not with ``n()`` to count the number in each group. Are you saying I have to make one function separetly that just counts e.g. group_count?

Comment: @David the biggest problem is that `n()` doesn't take any arguments so the way the current function is coded won't work. Like aosmith said, maybe `length()` will work the way it's currently written. If you absolutely have to use `n()`, then yeah, you either need a separate function or restructure this current function so that `func()` is not expecting arguments or that arguments are optional.

Comment: @dylanjm: I had tried ``length`` but it did not work either at first but them I tried it again and it works. I had probably mispelled ``length``. Thanks for your help.